# Specifying multiple default groups as hosts in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm looking for a way to specify multiple default groups as hosts in an Ansible playbook.  I've been using this method:

```
- name:  Do things on hosts
  hosts: "{{ specific_hosts | default('development') }}"
  tasks:  # do things on hosts
```

However I'm trying to avoid specifying hosts manually (it is error-prone), and the default hosts are inadequate if I want to run the same tasks against multiple groups of servers (for instance, development *and* QA).

I don't know if this is possible in a playbook:

```
- name:  Do things on hosts
  hosts: "{{ specific_hosts | default('development') && default('qa') }}"
```

I don't know if this is possible in an inventory:

```
[development]
1.2.3.4

[qa]
2.3.4.5

[dev_plus_qa]
development
qa
```

Creating multiple redundant tasks is undesirable as well - I would like to avoid forcing users to specify `specific_qa_hosts` (for instance) and I would like to avoid code repitition:

```
- name: Do things on DEV
  hosts: "{{ specific_hosts | default('development') }}"
- name: Do things on QA
  hosts: "{{ specific_hosts | default('qa') }}"
```

Is there any elegant way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible and is described in the [common patterns targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) documentation of Ansible.

So targeting two groups is as simple as `hosts: group1:group2`, and, so, your playbook becomes:

```yaml
- name:  Do things on hosts
  hosts: "{{ specific_hosts | default('development:qa') }}"
```

---

And if you rather want to achieve this via the inventory, this is also possible, [as described in the documentation examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/ini_inventory.html#examples):

So in your case, it would be:

```
[development]
1.2.3.4

[qa]
2.3.4.5

[dev_plus_qa:children]
development
qa
```

And then, as a playbook:

```yaml
- name:  Do things on hosts
  hosts: "{{ specific_hosts | default('dev_plus_qa') }}"
```