# Specifying multiple groups as hosts from different inventories in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a way to specify multiple groups as hosts in an Ansible playbook when the groups are located in separate inventories (this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65294947/specifying-multiple-default-groups-as-hosts-in-an-ansible-playbook), but different because that question assumes one single inventory).

Say I have a playbook called `change_things.yml`. Sometimes I want to change things in `development`, sometimes `qa`, sometimes `production`, etc.:

`ansible-playbook -i development -i production change_things.yml`.

Say there are separate inventories which look roughly like this:

```
# development inventory

[development]
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

The playbook above fails to run when `hosts` is not explicitly specified.

I have a few problems:

1. Using `hosts: all` seems harmful. If a user forgets to explicitly declare an inventory, I would imagine that Ansible inherits from whatever is in `/etc/ansible/hosts`.
2. Hard-coding host groups (`hosts: development:production`) is undesirable because I may want to run something like `ansible-playbook -i development -i qa change_things.yml` in the future.

I'm looking for a way to maintain separate inventories of hosts, but create playbooks in such a way that they can be executed against multiple combinations of host groups. I do not know how to tell Ansible "use these groups from these inventories".

Comment: Isolate development and production. Physically! Share common artifacts (playbooks, roles, inventory, vars ...) via version system.

Comment: @VladimirBotka This is just a contrived example to illustrate that I absolutely want to enforce this kind of isolation - you can think of these as `red` servers and `green` servers instead.  I do not want to have to maintain multiple playbooks with different default hosts but the same exact content. What's Ansible's version system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are indeed separating your different servers in different inventories, then you can name the groups with something common like `servers`

And then your inventory will follow

```
## this is development inventory 
[servers]
node1.dev.example.org
node2.dev.example.org
```

```
## this is qa inventory 
[servers]
node1.qa.example.org
node2.qa.example.org
```

And so your playbook will begin with

```yaml
- hosts: servers
```

And you can run this with

```sh
ansible-playbook -i development -i qa playbook.yml
```

---

Another way, but I have to say that I find this a overly complicated scenario, is to use the [`ansible_inventory_sources`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) special variable, then align the name of your inventory files with the host groups:

```
## this is development inventory 
[development]
node1.dev.example.org
node2.dev.example.org
```

```
## this is qa inventory 
[qa]
node1.qa.example.org
node2.qa.example.org
```

So the playbook will have an horrible:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ ansible_inventory_sources | map('basename') | map('regex_replace', '^([^\\.]*).*', '\\1') | list | join(':') }}"
```

Where

- [`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) would get the file name, e.g. `inventory.yml`
- The `regex_replace`, is not really needed in your use case, but is borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61931335/2123530) by @Zeitounator, and allows to remove any file extension, if you do have inventory file extension, like `development.yml`. And since my inventories do have the `.yml` extension, this is worth noting.
- the list is then [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join)'ed with a colon (`:`)  to fall back on your other question

And so running it, again with

```sh
ansible-playbook -i development -i qa playbook.yml
```

Will generate the host group pattern `development:qa`.

---

Here is a demo of what this give (using `debug` for the sake of the demo, but, as variables can be used in `host` too, this is the same):

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_inventory_sources | map('basename') | map('regex_replace', '^([^\\.]*).*', '\\1') | list | join(':') }}"
```

Give the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "developement:qa"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The `[servers]` idea is very elegant. On a side note, I actually ended up going a separate route altogether and just prompting for hosts/groups at runtime. Given the necessity of isolating hosts/inventories, I figured the prompt would work as an additional fail-safe.

Answer (score 4):

Q: **"*Tell Ansible 'use these groups from these inventories'*"**

A: Dynamically create a new group of hosts in the first play and use it afterward. For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: my_group
      loop: "{{ my_groups|from_yaml|map('extract', groups)|flatten }}"

- hosts: my_group
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

Given the inventories

```yaml
shell> cat hosts_prod
[prod]
prod1
prod2
prod3

shell> cat hosts_qa
[qaA]
qa1
qa2

[qaB]
qa3

shell> cat hosts_devel 
[develA]
devel1
devel2

[develB]
devel3
```

The command

```sh
ansible-playbook pb.yml -i hosts_prod -i hosts_qa -i hosts_devel -e "my_groups=[develA,qaB]"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [my_group] **********************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [devel2] => 
  inventory_hostname: devel2
ok: [devel1] => 
  inventory_hostname: devel1
ok: [qa3] => 
  inventory_hostname: qa3
```

Define any combination of inventories and *my_groups* on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks - this is a very interesting approach.